# How do I use the "Service Changed" characteristic to invalidate attributes cache?

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, micropython

I'm writing a small BT app on a microcontroller (using `aioble` on `Micropython`), but my question is more general on the BT spec itself.

Since I'm still developing the device, I keep adding/changing services and characteristics all the time, and found out that Chrome seems to cache the old services and chars UUID it found from previous runs. I understand this is done for performance and resources reasons, but I'd like to invalidate this cache on every boot.

I found out about the Generic Attribute Service (0x1801) and the Service Changed Characteristic (0x2A05) which suppose to do exactly this. I couldn't find official specs in the official [BT site](https://bluetooth.com) ([this link](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.generic_attribute.xml) for example seems to be broken), but found some other [resources](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/getting-started-with/9781491900550/ch04.html#gatt_service) that basically say that the server should send a notification with a value representing the range of handles that should be invalidated.

That sounds exactly like what I want, but nothing describes how do I represent a "handle range".. I basically want to erase all.

Any help? Also - do I write value to the char once at startup or I can send notification throughout the device's lifecycle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Bluetooth Core Specification v5.3](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/specs/core-specification-5-3/) describes the Service Changed Characteristic on page 1532:

> The Service Changed Characteristic Value is **two 16-bit Attribute Handles
> concatenated together** indicating the beginning and ending Attribute Handles
> affected by an addition, removal, or modification to a GATT-based service on
> the server. A change to a characteristic value is not considered a modification
> of the service. If a change has been made to any of the GATT service definition
> characteristic values other than the Service Changed characteristic value and
> the Client Supported Features characteristic value, the range shall also include
> the beginning and ending Attribute Handle for the GATT service definition.

This table describes the value decleration needed for the Service Changed Characteristic:
[image: Service Changed Characteristic Value declaration]

Comment: thanks! exactly what I was looking for. Something still doesn't seem to work for me - I don't need any fine-grained control, so I passed 0x0000 and 0xFFFF as the boundaries, assuming this would invalidate all cached information from this device, but I still don't see the newly added characteristics. In my server code, I notify the client immediately upon connecting (with the data of the 4 bytes 0x0000FFFF). Do I need to do anything else?

Comment: Bluetooth stacks handle the Service Changed Characteristic differently. For example, just the existence of the Service Changed Characteristic causes iOS to simply not cache anything at all for this specific device whereas Android requires the indication to be sent. I'm not sure how Chrome (We are talking about the browser here, aren't we?) handles this part of the Bluetooth spec

Comment: Yes. Chrome. I wasn't aware that there are differences there. Would expect this to be defined in the BT specs...  Thanks! I'll try to ask in Chrome forums.

Comment: The Bluetooth specs are actually not that strictly defined as the name suggests

Comment: Hi, can someone help with this pls. I've been wrecking my head for a few days now. Is it possible to provide a simple example of how to achieve this? I am using NRF connect and I can see the service 0x1801 but not sure how to deal with the 0x2A05. Is this something that should be available on the server or to send a request from device to the iOS? It will be greatly appreciated

Comment: @GeorgeB the Service Changed characteristic (0x2A05) is an optional characteristic, it does not need to be there. Maybe your device does not support it

Answer (score 0):

This answers is to complete the official answer (for which I am so grateful). Hopefully will avoid others (noobs like me) not that familiar with bt stack spending agonising days.

On iOS even though advertisement data had different name and service, it will still get the cached data on connection. Using nRF connect to connect and disconnect from device, log will look like this

```
    00:09:38.902 > connected status 1
    00:09:39.204 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=1, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
    00:09:39.264 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=6, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
    00:09:39.324 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=9, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
    00:09:39.384 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=1A, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
    00:09:44.605 > connected status 0
    00:09:46.233 > connected status 1 // NOTICE NO SUBSEQUENT SERVICE REQUESTED
    00:09:58.525 > connected status 0
```

But you would like the log to look like this:

```
00:09:38.902 > connected status 1
00:09:39.204 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=1, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:39.264 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=6, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:39.324 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=9, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:39.384 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=1A, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:44.605 > connected status 0
00:09:46.233 > connected status 1
00:09:46.494 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=1, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:46.554 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=6, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:46.614 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=9, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:46.674 > get_service pdu_type=E, attOpcode=10, st_hd=1A, end_hd=FFFF, att_type=2800
00:09:58.525 > connected status 0
```

In my case the only way to solve this was to add service changed 0x1801 and characteristic changed 0x2A05.

To spear you going through the [BT specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JLNZG.png) here are the important magic numbers

[image]

As you could guess after all these, I am still not proficient enough with bt stack so excuse me if terms are not correct. They key points would be that service 0x1801 should be on handle 6 and characteristic 0x2A05 on 7,8 and have the indicate flag.
The result on nRF should look like this:
[image]