# How can I refresh BLE Services while connected in iOS or B4i

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I'm developing an app that has to interface with an BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) device, that I also have to make.

I use B4i (from [B4X suite](https://www.b4x.com)) to develop the iOS app, but it **support also native Objective-C** code in it... so If you have a solution for the following problem in the native language is ok, also in Swift, just to point in some direction.

I want to implement a sort of **custom security mechanism**… and actually *I already successfully  did it* on **device-side**, so no problems there.

But this mechanism **NEEDS** the fact that the connected smartphone (iPhone) must be able to refresh the advertised services list while connected **because a service starts in a second moment, after connection**.

I tested my device (Esp32) using "nRF Connect" App by Nordic on **Android**, and there is a "refresh services" button that enables me to update the services list runtime (while connected)... so on Android side I'm covered.
[image: Refresh services button on Android app]

I've to understand if it is possibile also on iOS, and if yes... someone of you can help me understand how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Call [`-[CBPeripheral discoverServices:]`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheral/1518706-discoverservices?language=objc) a second time. Make sure that your device sends a [`Service Changed`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73514239/how-do-i-use-the-service-changed-characteristic-to-invalidate-attributes-cache) indication so that the OS knows to re-scan. (iOS doesn't necessarily honor this as tightly as the spec allows, but just follow the spec and it should work correctly.)

Comment: thank you for the answer, I will try to translate this in B4X language.

Comment: Do you know how to Send the indication for service changed with Arduino Framework?

Answer (score 0):

iOS refresh in B4i way has been done here:

https://www.b4x.com/android/forum/threads/b4x-ble-refresh-available-services-and-characteristics-missing-feature.146503/